# Where are the gastralia (stomach ribs) attached?

Tags: zoology, anatomy

Crocodiles and some dinosaurs have a second set of ribs between the sternum and pelvis called [gastralia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gastralium). Where are the gastralia attached to the rest of the skeleton?